# KeyValue binding NSNumber with Quartz Composer

Tags: objective-c, binding, key-value, quartz-composer

I received an example Quartz Composer app, made in Xcode 5.  The App has several parameters published in the .qtz file.  I would like to manually add UI sliders / buttons to control the parameters, but am having issues.  I will post edited snippets for reference.

I tried to bind a slider to this AppDelegate:

In the AppDelegate.h:

```
int amount;
@property int amount;
```

In the AppDelegate.m file;

```
@synthesize amount;

-(void) awakeFromNib{
amount = 50;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
[QCView [NSNumber numberWithInt:amount] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

My problems: awakeFromNib does not update the slider to '50', and the amount is not being 'seen' by the NSNumber.

I contacted the author of this example, and he replied;

"You can't see it because you do not "listen" to the "amount" changes. You have to ask :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"amount" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];"
```

"So you have to add something in the "observeValueForKeyPath..." function :

```
else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"amount"])
{
    NSLog(@"AMOUNT = %d", self.amount);
    [myQCView [NSNumber numberWithInt:amount] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
}"
```

I tried this, and received two errors:
. Unexpected interface name 'NSNumber': expected expression
. Parse Issue Expected ']' To match this '['

Is there a simple way to Key-Value bind a slider to an NSNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get rid of the compile error you want to use either

```
[myQCView setDefaultValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:amount] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

or

```
[myQCView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:amount] forKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

I don't know much about QC but here's how I found your compile error: [QCCompositionPickerView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/QCCompositionPickerView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html)